# How to figure out what block with similar classes cross out fixed block (getBoundingClientRect)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, overlay

I have this problem. I have carousel of div blocks of different color. Let's named them ONE , TWO and THREE. Аbove them there is fixed block named - "INFO". So, it setteled between two blocks. If block ONE crosses over Info block on more then 80% I want to write in console "1". I don't have any ideas of how to figure out what specific block is under INFO.
P.S: Now i write in console 'hello' if carousel's blocks are crossing over the Info block, but i need to write the ID of carousel's blocks.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel">
            <!-- Carousel -->
            <div class="carousel-content">

                <div class="slide slide-1">
                    <div>1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide-2">
                    <div>2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide-3">
                    <div>3</div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Fixed Block-->
            <div class="infoblock">
                <div>INFO</div>
            </div>

            <!-- Scroll Buttons -->
            <div class="nav nav-left">
                <div class="ion-chevron-left carousel-arrow-icon-left"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav nav-right">
                <div class="ion-chevron-right carousel-arrow-icon-right"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .4s;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: left .4s cubic-bezier(.47,.13,.15,.89);
}

.slide-1{
    background-color:cyan;
}

.slide-2 {
    background-color: green;
}

.slide-3 {
    background-color: red;
}


.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: rgba(150,150,150,.3);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-left {
  left: -25px;
}

.nav-right {
  right: -25px;
}


.infoblock{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:darkorange;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -5vh;
    margin-left: 10vw;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
var carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
var carouselContent = document.querySelector('.carousel-content');
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var arrayOfSlides = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
var carouselDisplaying;
var screenSize;
setScreenSize();
var lengthOfSlide;

function addClone() {
    var lastSlide = carouselContent.lastElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    lastSlide.style.left = (-lengthOfSlide) + "px";
    carouselContent.insertBefore(lastSlide, carouselContent.firstChild);
}

function removeClone() {
    var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
    firstSlide.parentNode.removeChild(firstSlide);
}

function moveSlidesRight() {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    var width = 0;

    slidesArray.forEach(function (el, i) {
        el.style.left = width + "px";
        width += lengthOfSlide;
    });
    addClone();
}
moveSlidesRight();

function moveSlidesLeft() {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    slidesArray = slidesArray.reverse();
    var maxWidth = (slidesArray.length - 1) * lengthOfSlide;

    slidesArray.forEach(function (el, i) {
        maxWidth -= lengthOfSlide;
        el.style.left = maxWidth + "px";
    });
}

window.addEventListener('resize', setScreenSize);

function setScreenSize() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 500) {
        carouselDisplaying = 3;
    } else if (window.innerWidth >= 300) {
        carouselDisplaying = 2;
    } else {
        carouselDisplaying = 1;
    }
    getScreenSize();
}

function getScreenSize() {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    lengthOfSlide = (carousel.offsetWidth / carouselDisplaying);
    var initialWidth = -lengthOfSlide;
    slidesArray.forEach(function (el) {
        el.style.width = lengthOfSlide + "px";
        el.style.left = initialWidth + "px";
        initialWidth += lengthOfSlide;
    });
}


var rightNav = document.querySelector('.nav-right');
rightNav.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

var moving = true;
function moveRight() {
    if (moving) {
        moving = false;
        var lastSlide = carouselContent.lastElementChild;
        lastSlide.parentNode.removeChild(lastSlide);
        carouselContent.insertBefore(lastSlide, carouselContent.firstChild);
        removeClone();
        var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
        firstSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', activateAgain);
        moveSlidesRight();
    }
}

function activateAgain() {
    var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
    moving = true;
    firstSlide.removeEventListener('transitionend', activateAgain);
}

var leftNav = document.querySelector('.nav-left');
leftNav.addEventListener('click', moveRight);


function moveLeft() {
    if (moving) {
        moving = false;
        removeClone();
        var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
        firstSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', replaceToEnd);
        moveSlidesLeft();
    }
}

function replaceToEnd() {
    var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
    firstSlide.parentNode.removeChild(firstSlide);
    carouselContent.appendChild(firstSlide);
    firstSlide.style.left = ((arrayOfSlides.length - 1) * lengthOfSlide) + "px";
    addClone();
    moving = true;
    firstSlide.removeEventListener('transitionend', replaceToEnd);
}




carouselContent.addEventListener('mousedown', seeMovement);

var initialX;
var initialPos;
function seeMovement(e) {
    initialX = e.clientX;
    getInitialPos();
    carouselContent.addEventListener('mousemove', slightMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', moveBasedOnMouse);
}

function slightMove(e) {
    if (moving) {
        var movingX = e.clientX;
        var difference = initialX - movingX;
        if (Math.abs(difference) < (lengthOfSlide / 4)) {
            slightMoveSlides(difference);
        }
    }
}

function getInitialPos() {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    initialPos = [];
    slidesArray.forEach(function (el) {
        var left = Math.floor(parseInt(el.style.left.slice(0, -2)));
        initialPos.push(left);
    });
}

function slightMoveSlides(newX) {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    slidesArray.forEach(function (el, i) {
        var oldLeft = initialPos[i];
        el.style.left = (oldLeft + newX) + "px";
    });
}

function moveBasedOnMouse(e) {
    var finalX = e.clientX;
    if (initialX - finalX > 0) {
        moveRight();
    } else if (initialX - finalX < 0) {
        moveLeft();
    }
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', moveBasedOnMouse);
    carouselContent.removeEventListener('mousemove', slightMove);
}
/* Blocks Overlapping*/
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");

function checkOverlap(ele1, ele2) {
    const boundings1 = ele1.getBoundingClientRect();
    const boundings2 = ele2.getBoundingClientRect();

    const top1 = parseInt(boundings1.top);
    const height1 = parseInt(boundings1.height);
    const top2 = parseInt(boundings2.top);

    const overlap = 1 - (top2 - top1) / height1;

    if (overlap >= 0.8) {
        ele2.classList.add("overlap-80");
        console.log('hello');
    }


}

checkOverlap(boxes[0], boxes[1]);
checkOverlap(boxes[2], boxes[3]);
checkOverlap(boxes[4], boxes[5]);
```

Comment: If you know that `INFO` box is smaller than the slides, you can simply use `document.elementsFromPoint()` for each corner of `INFO` box to get list of elements under each corner.

Comment: Can you write an example with my situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `INFO` box is always smaller than the slides, you can use `document.elementsFromPoint()` on four corners if it to get list of slides at these points:

```js
var carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
var carouselContent = document.querySelector('.carousel-content');
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var arrayOfSlides = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
var carouselDisplaying;
var screenSize;
setScreenSize();
var lengthOfSlide;

function addClone() {
    var lastSlide = carouselContent.lastElementChild.cloneNode(true);
    lastSlide.style.left = (-lengthOfSlide) + "px";
    carouselContent.insertBefore(lastSlide, carouselContent.firstChild);
}

function removeClone() {
    var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
    firstSlide.parentNode.removeChild(firstSlide);
}

function moveSlidesRight() {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    var width = 0;

    slidesArray.forEach(function (el, i) {
        el.style.left = width + "px";
        width += lengthOfSlide;
    });
    addClone();
}
moveSlidesRight();

function moveSlidesLeft() {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    slidesArray = slidesArray.reverse();
    var maxWidth = (slidesArray.length - 1) * lengthOfSlide;

    slidesArray.forEach(function (el, i) {
        maxWidth -= lengthOfSlide;
        el.style.left = maxWidth + "px";
    });
}

window.addEventListener('resize', setScreenSize);

function setScreenSize() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 500) {
        carouselDisplaying = 3;
    } else if (window.innerWidth >= 300) {
        carouselDisplaying = 2;
    } else {
        carouselDisplaying = 1;
    }
    getScreenSize();
}

function getScreenSize() {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    lengthOfSlide = (carousel.offsetWidth / carouselDisplaying);
    var initialWidth = -lengthOfSlide;
    slidesArray.forEach(function (el) {
        el.style.width = lengthOfSlide + "px";
        el.style.left = initialWidth + "px";
        initialWidth += lengthOfSlide;
    });
}


var rightNav = document.querySelector('.nav-right');
rightNav.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

var moving = true;
function moveRight() {
    if (moving) {
        moving = false;
        var lastSlide = carouselContent.lastElementChild;
        lastSlide.parentNode.removeChild(lastSlide);
        carouselContent.insertBefore(lastSlide, carouselContent.firstChild);
        removeClone();
        var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
        firstSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', activateAgain);
        moveSlidesRight();
    }
}

function activateAgain() {
    var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild.nextSibling; /*changed*/
    moving = true;
    firstSlide.removeEventListener('transitionend', activateAgain);
}


var leftNav = document.querySelector('.nav-left');
leftNav.addEventListener('click', moveRight);


function moveLeft() {
    if (moving) {
        moving = false;
        removeClone();
        var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
        firstSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', replaceToEnd);
        moveSlidesLeft();
    }
}

function replaceToEnd() {
    var firstSlide = carouselContent.firstElementChild;
    firstSlide.parentNode.removeChild(firstSlide);
    carouselContent.appendChild(firstSlide);
    firstSlide.style.left = ((arrayOfSlides.length - 1) * lengthOfSlide) + "px";
    addClone();
    moving = true;
    firstSlide.removeEventListener('transitionend', replaceToEnd);
}




carouselContent.addEventListener('mousedown', seeMovement);

var initialX;
var initialPos;
function seeMovement(e) {
    initialX = e.clientX;
    getInitialPos();
    carouselContent.addEventListener('mousemove', slightMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', moveBasedOnMouse);
}

function slightMove(e) {
    if (moving) {
        var movingX = e.clientX;
        var difference = initialX - movingX;
        if (Math.abs(difference) < (lengthOfSlide / 4)) {
            slightMoveSlides(difference);
        }
    }
}

function getInitialPos() {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    initialPos = [];
    slidesArray.forEach(function (el) {
        var left = Math.floor(parseInt(el.style.left.slice(0, -2)));
        initialPos.push(left);
    });
}

function slightMoveSlides(newX) {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var slidesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides);
    slidesArray.forEach(function (el, i) {
        var oldLeft = initialPos[i];
        el.style.left = (oldLeft + newX) + "px";
    });
}

function moveBasedOnMouse(e) {
    var finalX = e.clientX;
    if (initialX - finalX > 0) {
        moveRight();
    } else if (initialX - finalX < 0) {
        moveLeft();
    }
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', moveBasedOnMouse);
    carouselContent.removeEventListener('mousemove', slightMove);
}
/* Blocks Overlapping*/
/*changed*/
const infoBox = document.querySelector(".infoblock>div");
function checkOverlap() {
    const info = infoBox.getBoundingClientRect();

    let data = [],
        slide = document.querySelector('.slide').getBoundingClientRect(),
        list = [];

    // check elements at each corner of info block and several points within
    for(let x = 0, cache = {}; x < Math.round(info.width / (slide.width/3)); x++)
    {
      for(let y = 0; y < Math.round(info.height / (slide.height/3)); y++)
      {
        const  X = Math.min(info.right-1, info.left + slide.width * x),
               Y = Math.min(info.bottom-1, info.top + slide.height * y);

        if (cache[X + "x" + Y])
          continue;

        list = list.concat(cache[X + "x" + Y] = document.elementsFromPoint(X, Y));
      }
    }
    //leave only slides and remove any duplicates
    list = list.filter((item, pos) => item.classList.contains("slide") && list.indexOf(item) === pos);
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
      const slide = list[i];
      const box = slide.getBoundingClientRect(),
            width = Math.max(Math.min(box.right, info.right) - Math.max(box.left, info.left), 0),
            height = Math.max(Math.min(box.bottom, info.bottom) - Math.max(box.top, info.top), 0),
            overlapX = width / info.width,
            overlapY = height / info.height,
            overlapArea = (width * height) / (info.width * info.height);

      data[data.length] = {slide: slide, area: overlapArea, x: overlapX, y: overlapY}
    }
    return data;
}

/* demo */
let infoRect = infoBox.getBoundingClientRect(),
    theta = Math.random() * 10,
    gamma = Math.random() * 1,
    dragX = 0,
    dragY = 0,
    pause = true;

document.onmousedown = function(e)
{
  if (e.target === infoBox.parentNode)
    return infoBox.parentNode.classList.add("resize");

  if (e.target != infoBox)
    return;

  dragX = e.x - infoBox.parentNode.offsetLeft;
  dragY = e.y - infoBox.parentNode.offsetTop;
  document.body.classList.add("drag");
}
document.onmouseup = function(e)
{
  if (!document.body.classList.contains("drag") && !infoBox.parentNode.classList.contains("resize"))
    return;

  document.body.classList.remove("drag");
  infoBox.parentNode.classList.remove("resize");
  demoInfo(true);
}
document.onmousemove = function(e)
{
  const isMove =  document.body.classList.contains("drag");
  if (!isMove && !infoBox.parentNode.classList.contains("resize"))
    return;

  if (isMove)
  {
    infoBox.parentNode.style.left = (e.x - dragX) + "px";
    infoBox.parentNode.style.top = (e.y - dragY) + "px";
  }
  demoInfo();
}

//we can use parent container to listen for transition events
document.querySelector(".carousel-content").addEventListener("transitionend", demoInfo);

function isOverlapped(node, data)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    if (data[i].slide === node)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
function demoInfo(moved)
{
  const r = infoBox.getBoundingClientRect();
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--size', Math.min(r.height, Math.min(r.width, 100)) / 76 + 'em')
  const data = checkOverlap();
  data.sort((a,b) => b.area - a.area); //sorted by area
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  for(let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
  {
    slides[i].classList.toggle("overlapMost", data.length && slides[i] === data[0].slide)
    slides[i].classList.toggle("overlap", isOverlapped(slides[i], data))
  }
  if (data.length)
  {
    infoBox.textContent = "Slide " + data[0].slide.textContent.trim() + " overlap\nArea:" + Math.round(data[0].area * 100) + "%\nWidth:" + Math.round(data[0].x * 100) + "%\nHeight:" + Math.round(data[0].y * 100) + "%";
  }
  else
  {
    infoBox.textContent = "no overlap\n\ndrag me";
  }
  if (moved)
  {
    console.clear();
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      console.log("Slide " + data[i].slide.textContent.trim() + " ( " + Array.prototype.indexOf.call(data[i].slide.parentNode.children, data[i].slide) + " child) overlap area: " + Math.round(data[i].area * 100) + "%, X: " + Math.round(data[i].x *100) + "%, Y: " + Math.round(data[i].y *100) + "%");
    }
  }
}
demoInfo();
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .4s;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: left .4s cubic-bezier(.47,.13,.15,.89);
}

.slide > div
{
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.slide-1{
    background-color:cyan;
}

.slide-2 {
    background-color: green;
}

.slide-3 {
    background-color: red;
}
.slide-4 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.slide-5 {
    background-color: lightpink;
}


.nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: rgba(150,150,150,.3);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav-left {
  left: -25px;
}

.nav-right {
  right: -25px;
}


.infoblock{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:darkorange;
    z-index: 2;
/*    margin-top: -5vh;
    margin-left: 10vw;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
font-size: 0.7em;
font-size: var(--size);
white-space: pre;
min-width: 20%;
min-height: 80%;
cursor: move;
top: 5vh;
left: 10vw;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px gray;
resize: both;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
  }

.infoblock > div
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlap
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 black inset;
  z-index: 2;
}

.overlapMost
{
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px blue inset;
  z-index: 2;
}

body.drag
{
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="carousel">
            <!-- Carousel -->
            <div class="carousel-content">

                <div class="slide slide-1">
                    <div>1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide-2">
                    <div>2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide-3">
                    <div>3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide-4">
                    <div>4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide slide-5">
                    <div>5</div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Fixed Block-->
            <div class="infoblock">
                <div>Drag Me</div>
            </div>

            <!-- Scroll Buttons -->
            <div class="nav nav-left">
                <div class="ion-chevron-left carousel-arrow-icon-left"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="nav nav-right">
                <div class="ion-chevron-right carousel-arrow-icon-right"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

P.S.
There is a bug in your code where `transitionend` event not being removed when moved to the right, because it's trying remove it from the first slide, but the slide with the event listener by that time was already moved to second position.